# Chart.js - add information ON HOVER to the bubbles

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I want to create bubbles that contain not only x, y and r but other additional information.
I'm creating a chart where there is a map, and the bubbles represent earthquakes.
when the mouse moves over, they show magnitude -- this doesn't happen.

```
var ctx = $("#myChart");

var bubble = new Chart(ctx, {
"type": "bubble",

"data": {
    /* Omitted */
},

options: {
    animation: false,
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{ //xAxes
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                suggestedMax: 80
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{ //xAxes
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
                suggestedMax: 80
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
});
```